# How to display custom product field on WooCommerce checkout page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to display custom product field `checkout_name` on the checkout page but I can't seem to figure out how. I'm following checkout hooks visual guide from [here](https://www.tychesoftwares.com/woocommerce-checkout-page-hooks-visual-guide-with-code-snippets/).

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details', 'custom_before_checkout_form', 10 );
function custom_before_checkout_form( $cart_data ){
    $meta_key = 'checkout_name';

    $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];

    $meta_value = get_post_meta( $product_id, $meta_key, true );

    if( !empty( $cart_data ) )
        $custom_items = $cart_data;

    if( !empty($meta_value) ) {
        $custom_items[] = array(
            'key'       => __('Store Name', 'woocommerce'),
            'value'     => $meta_value,
            'display'   => $meta_value,
        );
    }
    return $custom_items;
}
```

Comment: Custom checkout fields have to be **inside** the checkout form. If not the field values are not posted on submission.

Comment: I see, would `woocommerce_before_checkout_billing_form` be inside of the form? I tried that hook as well but it's not working. I would love to display the field around billing details and not with the order details.

Comment: Please have a look to the [Woocommerce template `checkout/form-checkout.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3.6.0/templates/checkout/form-checkout.php) code... you will see which hooks are inside (after) the `<form>` tag … **Note:** The Templates [checkout/form-billing.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3.6.0/templates/checkout/form-billing.php) and [checkout/form-shipping.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3.6.0/templates/checkout/form-billing.php) are called inside it (and some others more too), for info.

Comment: Seems like `woocommerce_before_checkout_billing_form` is inside or I'm missing something?

Comment: But also after "form" tag it shows the hook: `woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details`. So would be great to display the field here, if not possible, then on `woocommerce_before_checkout_billing_form`

Comment: I can confirm I tried this hook and it's displaying the text inside of checkout form: `add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details', 'wpdesk_checkout_hello', 5 );
/**
 * Add "hello" text before WooCommerce checkout form
 *
 */
function wpdesk_checkout_hello() {
  echo '<h2>Hello there! Happy shopping!</h2>';
}`

Comment: But still unable to display the custom field..

Comment: I also tried this way but still no luck: `add_action('woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details', 'custom_before_checkout_form', 10);
function custom_before_checkout_form( $cart_item ){
    if($cart_item->object){
        foreach($cart_item->object->get_items() as $item_values){
        // Get the product ID for simple products (not variable ones)
        $product_id = $item_values['product_id'];
        $output = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'checkout_name', true );
        echo '<div align="center">' . $output . '<br></div>';
    }
}
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom checkout fields need **to be inside the checkout form**. If not the field values are not posted on submission.

There is also some errors in your code. Try the following instead using a hook located inside the checkout form, just before billing fields *(assuming that the custom product field `checkout_name` exist)*.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details', 'custom_before_checkout_form' ); 
function custom_before_checkout_form(){
    // Loop though cart items 
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ) { 
        // Get the WC_Product Object 
        $product = $item['data'];

        echo '<div align="center">' . $product->get_meta( 'checkout_name' ) . '</div><br>'; 
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should better work.